# Knitting a Rmd document with errors without showing them

Tags: r, knitr

I'd like to knit my Rmd document for educational purposes. The code may be wrong in many cases. I don't want any error messages, just being able to knit the document to HTML, for instance. Is this possible? I have used error=TRUE, however, this allows to knit but showing errors. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: What I mean is that the document is knitted correctly, but I would like to hide the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code chunk in the beginning of your `Rmd` document and it will do what you want:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, eval = FALSE)
```
````

Alternatively, you could do `eval = FALSE` in each of the code chunk that you do not want to get an error message from. However, the first approach will save you time.

Comment: In this case the code is not being executed, just displayed.  I think OP wants to execute the code, but does not want to print the error messages that are generated.

Comment: @Sandwichnick if you execute a code but hide its result, the result will be the same with not evaluating the code.

Comment: No, actually, this is great! I did not want my code executed at all.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to execute code but did not want the error messages in your knitted document.


This is not evaluated, there is no print message:
```{r noteval, eval=FALSE, error=TRUE}
print("hello World")
stop("This is an Error Message")
```

this is evaluated, a print message is generated, but also the error message
```{r eval, eval=TRUE, error=TRUE}
print("hello World")
stop("This is an Error Message")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be executed without any error message, you could try to wrap your code with a `try()` statement.

```
try({
  code...
},silent = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could put the risky code in a `try` block with a silent parameter.

```
try({
   TRUE <- FALSE
    },
    silent=TRUE
    )
```

no error message will be generated